# How to loop through multiple divs

Tags: jquery

I have a structure like this :

```
<div>
     <div> 
         <div onclick="someFunction(this)"></div>
     </div>
     <div> 
         <div onclick="someFunction(this)"></div>
     </div>
     ..
     ..
</div>
```

So inside my `someFunction()`, how do I iterate through all the `div`s that have the `onclick` implemented on them?

I've thought of the following:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children().each( function () { } );
```

But somehow I'm totally sure that it's wrong. Because doing `parent()` twice might take me to the topmost parent, but after that iterating through each child won't actually iterate through all of the `div`s that have `onclick` on them, instead, it'll iterate through the `div`s one level above it. And if I do `children()` again and then do `each()`, I don't think it'll do what I want.
Please guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why don't you just assign a class to all the divs with that onclick method implemented?

So you would do something like this

html

```
<div>
     <div> 
         <div class="someDiv"></div>
     </div>
     <div> 
         <div class="someDiv"></div>
     </div>
     ..
     ..
</div>
```

script

```
$(".someDiv").each(function(){
    somefunction(this);
});
```

Comment: Simple solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the grandfather element by chaining [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) into [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), then use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) with a [Has Attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector to match the `<div>` elements you're interested in:

```
$(this).parents().eq(1).find("div[onclick]").each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

If you want to exclude the current `<div>`, you can use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$(this).parents().eq(1).find("div[onclick]").not(this).each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it that way:

```
$('div[onclick*=someFunction]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to easily select all elements you want.

```
<div>
     <div> 
         <div class="myClass"></div>
     </div>
     <div> 
         <div class="myClass"></div>
     </div>
     ..
     ..
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    //All your elements which have a class myClass
    $elements = $('.myClass');

    $.each($elements,function(){
        //Here you are going through all your elements
    });

    $('.myClass').click(function(){
        //Here you are executing your function
        someFunction(this);
    });
});
```